# Fetch core data, NSException error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, fetch, nsexception

I working on an app using core data. The greatest part of the implementation worked out well but at the very very very last moment I get an NSException error. I can fetch the core data and put them in a string, but I can't put it in a textView, label or whatever.

This is the code for the fetch. 
    `NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Template"];
    self.template = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%@ viewDidLoad", [template valueForKey:@"name"]);
    self.nameStringString = [template valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@ viewDidLoad String", self.nameStringString);
    self.testLabel.text = self.nameStringString;`

I tested at a few moments in the code wether the data was still intact or it was missing. The code up here works fine until the last sentence. What should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is the error I get. After the error the app will be terminated. 
2015-09-03 21:20:54.511 ****[1640:671115] -[__NSArray0 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1255022a0

Comment: What do those NSLog statements show?

Comment: ggfgg,
    ggfgg,
    ggfgg,
    ggfgg,
    ggfgg,
    ggfgg,
    ggfgg

Comment: When I was coding the core data methods I made a few new objects instead of rewriting the old one. The last one was ggfgg as in a test.

Comment: OK, try `self.testLabel.text = self.nameStringString[0]`

Comment: tried it, get this error when implementing it in the code: Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSString * _Nullable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `executeFetchRequest` returns an NSArray, even if there is only one object to fetch.  You need to extract the individual members of the array before obtaining the `valueForKey`:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Template"];
NSArray *templateArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSManagedObject *firstTemplate = [templateArray firstObject];
self.nameStringString = [firstTemplate valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@ viewDidLoad String", self.nameStringString);
self.testLabel.text = self.nameStringString;
```

Comment: What should I do with "firstObject"? Getting an error there.

Comment: @user3638160 I've amended the code to use a local NSArray to hold the results of the fetch.  I think this should work.  Out of interest, what class is `self.template`?

Comment: That works amazing! But now I have another (small) problem. I want to fetch the latest. When I update or make a new object it fetches the first ever made. How could I change this?

Comment: Change `firstObject` to `lastObject`.

Comment: A big thanks! You've made my day :). Pretty dumb of myself that I didn't saw that last minor problem :P